# Methods to process asynchronously received form data

Tags: c#, async-await

I am having trouble wrapping my head around the async/await functionality in .NET 4.5.  I am using the code below in a Web API controller to catch multiple files from a form along with some other form data.  I have no control over the form or how it sends the data.

What I want to do is receive the files, get data from the form, read a database based on that form data, move the file(s), and update another database table.  With the below code I have no trouble getting the files or form data.  I get data from the database based on the formID passed in the form data.

It is when I uncomment the code near the bottom for writing back to the database that I run into issues.  If I had three files, only one of them gets moved before the catch block catches an exception.  I am assuming that my problem is related to the fact that the PostFile method is async.

What is the proper way of writing this code so that it works?

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostFile()
{
    // Check if the request contains multipart/form-data. 
    if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
    }

    string root = GetRootPath();
    var provider = new MyMultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);
    string logfile = root + "/form_data_output.txt";

    try
    {
        // Read the form data and return an async task. 
        await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

        string form_id = provider.FormData.Get("FormId");

        string driver_id = GetDriverID(form_id);  // returns an int as a string

        string location = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["storagePath"];
        location += form_id + "\\";

        //// make sure the new directory exists
        if (!Directory.Exists(location))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(location);
        }

        var keys = provider.FormData.Keys.Cast<string>();
        foreach (var k in keys.Where(k => k.StartsWith("FormViewer") == true))
        {
            string filename = provider.FormData.Get(k) + ".pdf";
            string type_key = "FormType_" + k.Substring(k.IndexOf('_') + 1);
            string type_value = provider.FormData.Get(type_key);

            // setup the full path including filename
            string path = root + "\\" + filename;
            string newFullPath = location + filename;

            // move the file
            File.Move(path, newFullPath);
            if (File.Exists(newFullPath))
            {
                 if (File.Exists(newFullPath))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        string conn_str = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["eMaintenanceConnection"].ConnectionString;
                        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conn_str))
                        {
                            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO eSubmittal_Document VALUES (null,@driver_id,@location,@doctype)");
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@driver_id", driver_id);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@location", location);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@doc_type", type_value);
                            conn.Open();
                            int c = await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                            conn.Close();
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        LogEntry(logfile, e.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
    catch (System.Exception e)
    {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the exception you get?

Comment: I have changed the commented code and wrapped it up in a try/catch block.  The exception is Invalid Operation: the connection is closed.

Comment: I should add that I use the same connection string earlier in the GetDriverID function so I know that the connection string is correct.

Comment: Wow.  I guess I am embarrassed now.  The SqlCommand code I used didn't include the connection variable.  Once I changed that I am good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`async` and `await` provide *natural program flow* for asynchronous code. So for the most part, you can just think about code the way you normally think about it:

> It is when I uncomment the code near the bottom for writing back to the database that I run into issues. If I had three files, only one of them gets moved before the catch block catches an exception.

Here's what I get from this:

- Your database code is throwing an exception.
- When the exception is thrown, it leaves the `foreach` loop to go to the `catch` handler.

Nothing unexpected there...

Comment: I agree about nothing unexpected.  I did find that the code thinks the connection is closed.  I made changes to catch that exception and I create the SqlConnection right there instead of pulling from another function.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to help very much without knowing the exception, but performing a *synchronous* database operation inside an async method seems like a bad idea to me. Try changing your code to use:

```
int c = await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
```

Comment: I was uncomfortable with my original.  Thanks for the suggestion.  I have stared at the code too long.